# Sun Grid Engine : jobs are not well balanced

Tags: sun, gridengine

I use Open Grid Scheduler (a fork/copy of Sun Grid Engine).

I have tried this configuration from **master**:

```
# qconf -mattr exechost complex_values slots=8 slave2
# qconf -mq all.q | grep slots
slots                 100,[slave1=1],[slave2=8]
```

**slave1** is down, then I run 10 `qsub` with a sleep example (so no CPU consumption) but only 4 jobs are run at the same time on **slave2** instead of I have put 8 slots.

What does I missed ?

PS: my goal is to provide infinite slots to force SGE to schedule only via consummable ressources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try running `qalter -w p` on one of the queued jobs to see why it doesn't start.  Also check the state of the queues to ensure they aren't in an alarmed state.